# Undefined reference error in c++ dynamic member

Tags: c++, linked-list, undefined-reference, modularity, code-separation

hi everyone im new to programming so excuse the noob question...
i tried every method to get through with the undefined refernce error but it keeps throwing that error at me
i tried using pointer "->" and the "::" sign and also the dot "."
what am i supposed to do? why cant it compile?

this is my cpp file:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "account.hpp"

using namespace std;

int Account::getAccountNumber()
    {
        return accountNumber;
    }
double Account::getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }
void Account::createAccount(LinkedList<Account>& accountsList, string name, int idNumber)
{
...
    case 1:
       accountsList.addFront(newAcc); //Where the error occurs.
        break;
    case 2:
        do
        {
            cout << "\n\tWhich position would you like to insert the\n"
                 << "\tnew account into?\n"
                 << "\tPosition number: #";
            cin >> target;
            if (cin.fail())
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(20,'\n');
                cout << "\n\n\tSorry, wrong input. Please enter a correct position.\n\n";
                system("pause");
            }
        }
        while(cin.fail());
        accountsList.addMiddle(newAcc, target); //and here
        break;
    case 3:
        accountsList.addEnd(newAcc); //and here
        break;
    }
    cout << "\n\n\tAccount Created Successfully\n\n"
         << accountsList; 
    system("pause");
}
```

and here is my .hpp

```
#ifndef ACCOUNT_HPP_INCLUDED
#define ACCOUNT_HPP_INCLUDED
#include "linkedlist.hpp"
#include "generic.hpp"

class Account : public GenericAccount
{
    int accountNumber;
    double balance;
public:
    Account(string name = "empty", int idNumber = 0, int accountNumber = 0, double balance = 0)
        :  GenericAccount(name, idNumber), accountNumber(accountNumber), balance(balance) {}
    int getAccountNumber();
    double getBalance();
    void createAccount(LinkedList<Account>&, string, int);
    void deposit(LinkedList<Account>&, Account&);
    void withdraw(LinkedList<Account>&, Account&);
    void displayAccount(LinkedList<Account>&, Account&);
    void deleteAccount(LinkedList<Account>&);

    friend istream& operator>> (istream& is, Account& x)
    {
        is >> x.accountNumber;
        return is;
    }

    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, Account& c)
    {
        os << "Account Number= " << c.getAccountNumber() << "\t"
           << "Balance= "<< c.getBalance() << endl;
        return os;
    }

    friend bool operator == (Account& a, Account& target)
    {
        return (a.getAccountNumber() == target.getAccountNumber());
    }

};


#endif // ACCOUNT_HPP_INCLUDED
```

the full project can be downloaded [HERE](http://www.mediafire.com/?kd9k2nkjgm7fklj) for refernce
THANK YOU ALL IN ADVANCE!

Comment: [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Is it `my.hpp` or `account.hpp` because you have included the latter in my.ccp

Comment: @gx_ thanks for the link i already check it out during my search for an answer

Comment: @UchiaItachi i meant thats my .hpp file not a file named my.hpp, sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that there is that the addFront method is not being defined for the account type (in fact any type). See [Why can templates only be implemented in the header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file) for a much better explanation.

Moving the contents of cpp inline in the .h file should do the trick. Another option is to rename the the .cpp file to a .inl and include it at the bottom of linkedList.hpp